# How to compare the P values in permutation testing or randomization by shuffling only one variable in dataframe

Tags: r, loops, statistics, data-science

I am writing loops or functions in R, and I still haven't really understood how to do that. Currently, I need to write a loop/function (not sure which one would be better) to create several results of Mixed models formula in the Permutation testing or randomization

sample dataset looks like:

```
dataset <- read.table(text = 
"ID A_2 B_2 C_2 A_1 B_1 C_1 chkgp
M1  10  20  60  30  54  33  Treatment
M1  20  50  40  33  31  44  Placebo
M2  40  80  40  23  15  66  Placebo
M2  30  90  40  67  67  66  Treatment
M3  30  10  20  22  89  77  Treatment
M3  40  50  30  44  50  88  Placebo
M4  40  30  40  42  34  99  Treatment
M4  30  40  50  33  60  80  Placebo",header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### I have shuffle chkgp  variable each time the model run and used the following code

```
mod1<-summary(lmerTest::lmer(A_2~B_1+sample(chkgp)+(1|ID),data = dataset))
mod1
P_value= 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(mod1$coefficients[3, 4])))
P_value
```

result model 1 after shuffule 1 time

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: A_2 ~ B_1 + sample(chkgp) + (1 | ID)
   Data: dataset

REML criterion at convergence: 44.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.7792 -0.4441  0.1185  0.3893  0.7734 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 122.52   11.069  
 Residual              10.15    3.186  
Number of obs: 8, groups:  ID, 4

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)            42.87450    6.49941  4.06743   6.597  0.00258 **
B_1                    -0.27492    0.09149  7.97033  -3.005  0.01702 * 
sample(chkgp)Treatment  1.74313    4.71095  8.33366   0.370  0.72060   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) B_1   
B_1         -0.433       
smpl(chkg)T  0.164 -0.748
[1] 0.7113693
```

#### Question 1: I need to find out the way to  compare and  check the actual P-value is same even after shuffling chkgp variable 1000

#### question 2: I need to write the loop run models 1000 times in each it need shuffle the chkgp variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset <- read.table(text = 
                        "ID A_2 B_2 C_2 A_1 B_1 C_1 chkgp
M1  10  20  60  30  54  33  Treatment
M1  20  50  40  33  31  44  Placebo
M2  40  80  40  23  15  66  Placebo
M2  30  90  40  67  67  66  Treatment
M3  30  10  20  22  89  77  Treatment
M3  40  50  30  44  50  88  Placebo
M4  40  30  40  42  34  99  Treatment
M4  30  40  50  33  60  80  Placebo",header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


storeP <- list(rep(NA, 1000))

for(i in 1:1000) {
  #dataset <- transform(dataset, chkgp = sample(chkgp))
  dataset$chkgp <- ifelse(runif(nrow(dataset)) > 0.5, "Treatment", "Placebo")
  mod1<-summary(lmerTest::lmer(A_2~B_1+sample(chkgp)+(1|ID),data = dataset))
  P_value= 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(mod1$coefficients[3, 4])))
  storeP[[i]] <- P_value
}

var(unlist(storeP)) == 0
```

I have two options of "shuffling the data":

1. randomly sorting the column chkgp: `transform(dataset, chkgp = sample(chkgp))`
2. randomly assigning "Treatment" and "Placebo" to the Variable at a 0.5 threshold: `ifelse(runif(nrow(dataset)) > 0.5, "Treatment", "Placebo"`

Comment: I just want to shuffle only the ##chkgp variable not all the variable

Comment: I just want to shuffle only the ##chkgp variable not all the variable

Comment: ```shuffleddata <- transform(dataset, chkgp = sample(chkgp))``` its not shuffle could please check it again

Comment: So what do you mean with shuffle? Randomly assigning "Treatment" and "Placebo" in the "chkgp" column? Shuffling from my understanding is randomly sample the given column rowwise...

Comment: the actual problem I am trying to solve we need to calculate mean difference or Pvalue of the model without shuffling date and then run 1000 models by shuffling the  chkgp data  to compare whether th both Pvalues are equally are not